# How can I get only the products that belong to a certain type added from the dashboar in django-oscar?

Tags: django-oscar

I want to filter the products that belong to a certain type of product and show them in an html file. The type of product is added from the django-oscar's default admin panel. I found the only solution on the internet that django-oscar-easyrec package might be helpful in this, but It is not installing stating that a lower version than 12 is required for easyrec. On the other hand any version lower than 12 is not compatible with django-oscar 1.6.7 thus I can't use easyrec. So I'm looking for an alternate solution to this package to achieve results. I'm new to django-oscar and I find their documentation difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get same type of products using  catalogue category

```
 recommend_products = Product.objects.active().filter(
                categories=product.categories.all()[0],
            ).exclude(pk=product.pk)
```